# How to open a .java file on mac

Tags: eclipse

I was sent an email with a .java file attachment, I need to open it in Eclipse, but whenever I click to download the file, it opens in the Brackets program, how do I get it to open in Eclipse? I use MAC and Safari as a browser

Comment: Why does it open Brackets?

Comment: I don't know, whenever I click to download a Java file that's been sent to me through email it automatically opens in Brackets